# I am running Appium 2.0 natively on Android Studio - Gradle Dependencies and Repository Necessities?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, appium-android, appium-java

I am developing a testing suite for an Android Application using Appium specifically for our UI testing. We decided that instead of using Eclipse IDE we would like to run our scripts through Android Studio (and eventually command line for CI/CD purposes). As Appium has recently migrated to version 2.0+, all the information I can find online for what dependencies are required for Appium (specifically in Android Studio) are all outdated by many years. I was wondering what dependencies/repositories/etc that should be included in my build.gradle file so that I can effectively execute my tests. Additionally, if anyone knows what imports are required in my Java class as well that would be great. I know what dependencies are required for the use of Appium in Eclipse and I will put them below if anyone can help me to translate them into Android Studio language.

These are the current versions I am using:

- Appium version: 2.0.0-rc.5
- Java version: 17.0.7
- UiAutomator2: 2.29.2
- Android Studio: Flamingo
- Gradle: 7.4.2

[This is the image of the Eclipse dependencies for (1) Appium java client, (2) Selenium support, and (3) Selenium java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xhq2.png)

[This is the image of the Eclipse dependencies for (1) the Testing dependency and (2) the Extent Reports dependency from Maven Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm3pk.png)

Here it is in code in case the images are blurry. Reminder these are the dependencies from the Eclipse IDE for running Appium 2.0 tests. These are all valid versions, from only a few weeks ago (mid June).

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version> 
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.0</version> 
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>7.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
```

Thank you very much!